# Any way to know before html content was shown in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Is any possible ways that I would like to know before html content was shown in uiwebview.
coz when I called to some url, It will take a few seconds to complete the whole page loading. Before loading was completed, some of the content was already shown. I would like to know before that content was shown or before start showing.

Answer (score 1):

UIWebView has a delegate protocol called [UIWebViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView%3ashouldStartLoadWithRequest%3anavigationType%3a). Two methods you should implement are – webViewDidStartLoad: notify monitoring object of when a site will about to load and – webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest: notify when there a certain request like click, submit, back/forward etc are being made